What does 有了 mean?
I've come across a sentence which reads:
几千年前，中国就有了“嫦娥奔月”的传说。
I can't figure out the meaning of 有了 in this sentence and how 有and 了 are combined together?
If I say
几千年前，中国就有“嫦娥奔月”的传说。
How would this sentence be different from the first one?

有了 means pregnant, of course.

it means "had had"


有了的意思是存在、拥有某物或某种状态。

这（有了）是一个非常普遍和常用的表达方式。
This （有了）is a very common and frequently used style of expression.
在日常对话和生活中，
In daily speech and life,
人们经常用这个词语来描述获取了某样物品、
people usually use this phrase to describe (having) acquired some kind of goods,
达到了某种状态或者获得了某种经验。
or (having) attained some kind of state or received some kind of experience.
例如，
For example,
当我们购买了一件新衣服，
when we buy some new clothes,
我们可能会说：
we can say:
“我终于有了这件我梦寐以求的衣服了。”
"I finally got my dream clothes."
这里，“有了”表示获取了这件衣服，
Here, “有了”expresses getting these clothes,
它的存在成为了我们的一部分。
these clothes become part of us.
又如，
again,
当我们学会了一项新技能，
when we learn a new skill,
我们可能会说：
we might say:
“我终于有了这项技能了。”
"I finally got this figured out."
这里，“有了”表示我们已经掌握了这项技能，
Here, “有了”expresses we have grasped this skill,
它已经成为我们的能力之一。
it has become one of our abilities.
总的来说，
In summary,
“有了”是一个简洁明了的表达方式，
“有了”is a concise, clear form of expression,
用于描述某物或某种状态的存在或获取。
used to describe something or the existence of some kind of state or acquisition.
在不同的语境中，
In different contexts,
它可以有不同的具体含义，
it may have different specific meanings,
但基本的意思都是某物或某种状态已经存在或者被获取。
but the basic meaning is something or some state or condition already exists or has been acquired.
这样的表达方式在口语和书面语中都非常常见，
This kind of expression frequently occurs in spoken and written language,
是人们日常交流中的常用词汇之一。
(it) is one of the phrases often used in daily social intercourse.

Usually Chinese people would say 几千年前，中国就有“嫦娥奔月”的传说。 rather than 几千年前，中国就有了“嫦娥奔月”的传说。
关于有了的例子通常会这样说，比如：

小明经过努力，在县城买了一套房子，他终于有了属于自己的一个家。


I'd say it indicates a change of state.
我已經不是老師了。
I'm not a teacher anymore. (Shows that he changed from being a teacher to not being a teacher.)
Here it means China went from not having to having this story.
As a native Chinese speaker, not having the 了 just sounds strange to me.
Hope this helped!

In this sentence, 有(have/has/possess) is a linking verb, rather than indicating completion, "了" acts as a tune modifier that adds certainty to "有" with a slight sense of sigh/exclamation.

几千年前，中国就有(already had)“嫦娥奔月”的传说。

几千年前，中国就有了(indeed/certainly already had)“嫦娥奔月”的传说。


Note that when a girl/woman says "我有了", it usually means she is pregnant.

that thing with the sigh is not thing

@JohnFrazer That thing is not a thing, it is "口氣" - 口氣中帶着感慨/驚嘆.
